# Multiple Imputation Variance

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation

I have been reading up on multiple imputation, and I am interested in the between-imputation variance. However, not in the estimation of the parameters, but in the imputed values themselves.

(1) Suppose $x$ is vector with some missing values. I then perform multiple imputations an infinite amount of times according to Rubin by drawing from the conditional distributions given the observed data and then take the between-imputation variance of the completed vectors

(2) Also suppose I also perform multiple imputations by drawing from the joint probability distribution an infinite amount of times. Then I take the between-imputation variance.

Under the MAR assumption, is the variance of (1)<(2)? If the observed values help predict the missing values, it seems like it is intuitively...